# Error when implementing AODV on ARM (SabreLIte)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux

I'm implementing the ad hoc **AODV** routing protocol on ARM based system Sabrelite http://boundarydevices.com/products/sabre-lite-imx6-sbc/ ......... After configuring and building the kernel that match to the one used on the board. I get the following errors:

error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
  __kernel_ulong_t loads[3]; /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */

error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
  __kernel_ulong_t totalram; /* Total usable main memory size */
  ^

/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:18:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
  __kernel_ulong_t freeram; /* Available memory size */
  ^

error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
  __kernel_ulong_t sharedram; /* Amount of shared memory */
  ^

/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:28:22: error: '__kernel_ulong_t' undeclared here (not in a function)
  char _f[20-2*sizeof(__kernel_ulong_t)-sizeof(__u32)]; /* Padding: libc5 uses this.. */
                      ^
make: *** [nl-arm.o] Error 1

As the errors suggested, it is something along with the cross compilation source tree but i don't know how on earth i get those errors because the used SDK works perfectly.

I followed the tutorial cited in the README file provided by AODV packages..

Has anyone ever experienced implementing AODV on ARM ? and did they got these errors

How can i resolve these issues ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the solution was to properly upgrade the makefile to work for post 2.6 kernel. If you happen to read this page: write your makefile like this:http://lwn.net/Articles/21823/